# maven-surefire-plugin consoleOutputReporter parameter doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, console, output, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm looking for solution to customize console test results output and found out that it is possible with implementation of `org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.SurefireConsoleOutputReporter` through plugin configuration parameter `<consoleOutputReporter>`.

I've created an implementation, however when I run `mvn clean test` I receive an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) on project navi-transfer-testing: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test for parameter consoleOutputReporter: Cannot find default setter in class org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.SurefireConsoleOutputReporter -> [Help 1]
```

I checked the source code of plugin and I really cannot find setter for this property - `org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireExecutionParameters` doesn't have appropriate setter and getter method.

I use plugin of **version 3.0.0-M6**

Doesn't it mean that property is defined but still not implemented in plugin so cannot be resolved?

Comment: In 3.0.0-M6, the only properties that can be set for `SurefireConsoleOutputReporter` are `disable` and `encoding`. Could you add the POM snippet you are trying to compose to the question?